# Matplotlib: Update positions and velocities in quiver()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a large number of files that contain data from a simulation. I want to use each file to save an image of a vector field using quiver(). Unfortunately, my method is really slow.

Here is a minimal working example of my code:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Number of files
N = 100000

n_points = 10000

for k in range(N):
    t0 = time.time()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,5))
    ax.axis("off")

    # Get data
    data = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(n_points, 4))
    x,y,vx,vy = data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], data[:,3]

    # Normalize and scale velocities
    norm = np.hypot(vx,vy)
    vx = vx / norm 
    vy = vy / norm 
    vx *= 0.05
    vy *= 0.05

    # Plot vectorfield
    ax.quiver(x, y, vx, vy, scale=1., width=0.001, units="xy")

    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, right=1, top=1, left=0)
    plt.savefig("image_" + str(k) + ".png", dpi=300)
    plt.close()

    print("%.2f" % (100.*(k+1.)/N) + " %" + " %.2f" % (time.time()-t0) + " images/s", end="\r")
```

Any ideas how I can speed things up? Right now I can save about one image every second. Given the large amount of data files, this takes several hours on my machine to complete.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I modified the code above according to the recommendations of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. However, the code is still really slow.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Number of files
N = 20

n_points = 20000

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(5,5))
ax.axis("off")
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, right=1, top=1, left=0)

for k in range(N):
    t0 = time.time()

    # Get data
    data = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(n_points, 4))
    x,y,vx,vy = data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], data[:,3]

    # Normalize and scale velocities
    norm = np.hypot(vx,vy)
    vx = vx / norm 
    vy = vy / norm 
    vx *= 0.05
    vy *= 0.05

    # Plot vectorfield
    q = ax.quiver(x, y, vx, vy, scale=1., width=0.001, units="xy")
    plt.savefig("image_" + str(k) + ".png", dpi=300)
    #q.remove()
    ax.clear()

    #plt.close()
    t.append(time.time()-t0)
    print("%.2f" % (100.*(k+1.)/N) + " %" + " %.2f" % (time.time()-t0) + " s/images", end="\r")
```

Before any improvements it took about 1.71 seconds for one image on average. Using `ax.clear()` is even slower with 1.81 seconds per image. Using `q.remove()` is a little bit faster and results in 1.61 seconds per image. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Don't create a new figure in each step; instead just remove the previous quiver and plot a new one.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest How can I do that? I tried moving `fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(5,5))` in front of the for-loop which results in empty images.

Comment: Most probably because you still close the figure. Remove `close` and also don't forget to `remove` previous quivers before drawing new ones.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest How do I `remove` previous quivers? Do I do that with `plt.clf()`?

Comment: No, `clf()` **cl**ears the **f**igure. You would want to clear the axes, `ax.clear()` or remove the quiver, `quiv.remove()`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I updated my question with your recommendations. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: No, what you show is precisely what I had in mind, though I would have expected to lead to a gain of more than 0.1 seconds. Maybe worth noting that 20000 points is *a lot*, so possibly matplotlib isn't the right tool for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Change dpi to None that will speed up image creating by 2.

```
plt.savefig("image_" + str(k) + ".png", dpi=None)
```

Comment: But I need high quality images for further processing.